# Create Custom HTML TAG While DOM loading

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, domdocument

I am on the way of creating `Live Editor`,And in that i have to define a function which occurs when `DOM` Start loading or while Loading..

So in that i have to create a Custom HTML Tag and place it in `Document`,but not in `Body` tag,

So if user call it from `<head>` it just occurs and start its Working whether to see that if `DOM` loads or not and create a Custom `TAG` inside or outside the `<html>`.

Just for Now i write Something that works as given in Jsfiddle - `onload`,`onDomready`,`No Wrap - in <body>` but i want it to work in `No Wrap - in <head>`

So How to achieve this task ? Is it Possible to create or Add custom TAG before DOM loads ?

Here's My code -

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/3Bayt/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "So in that i have to create a Custom HTML Tag and place it in
>   Document,but not in Body tag"

For that look into `createDocumentFragment` and `createElement` :

```
var newfrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = "Test";
newfrag.appendChild(element);
```

This will create the element but not place it within the html body.

---

**RE: custom attributes**

Valid custom elements in HTML5 ( `<!DOCTYPE html>` ) require the name to contain a dash ( - )

And we would need to register and initialise them

```
var newElement = document.registerElement('custom-element');
var element = document.createElement( new newElement() );
```

---

These are a couple of answers to.

1. Creating elements outside of the `<body>`
2. How to use custom attributes ( html5 )

Not sure how far that gets you ... hope helps in someway.

---

**Update/Fix : ** Ashish was able to get the code working on his setup by targeting the `<HTML>` tag rather than the `<body>` tag and provided the following demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/3Bayt/3

Comment: Ya , you right i also Google alot,by using this similar keywords but not find as much,But I'll try as you say,if it works then update you soon ? Thanks for being the part ! @Rob Sedgwick

Comment: Hi @AshishMishra, you just pasted this code into the middle of your jsfiddle : )

Comment: This is just answering your question : "Is it Possible to create or Add custom TAG before DOM loads ?" - yes ^^ - After that, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve and will need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Ohk,I'll try for it,Thanks @Rob Sedgwick :)

Comment: Actually i need that ,in `Jsfiddle` there is a `No Wrap - in <head>` my code works all where,but not in head because it not find the body tag as it is loading, So i want to create element that should not depend on body tag ? @Rob Sedgwick

Comment: A `element = document.createElement("div");` statement in the `<head>` does not depend on the `<body>` tag

Comment: why the need to have  all this stuff run in the `<head>` anyway ?

Comment: yes can't call `document.body` if the body is not there yet

Comment: Its works By getting `html` http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/3Bayt/3/ @Rob Sedgwick,Thanks for all the suggestions :) !!

Comment: I don't know what i did, but thrilled its working :) great stuff @AshishMishra - yes `<html>` is there, but beware of some browsers, they might complain because `<html>` is not closed yet.

Comment: LOLZZ...I am using IE environment .. its a Native Desktop Windows 8 HTML5 App :) @Rob Sedgwick,Again Thanks... :)

Comment: Please update your answer,If you think its good, to post it.. So i can accept it as answer @Rob Sedgwick

Answer (score 1):

It is very bad practice to use a custom HTML tag in (X)HTML:

```
var _A = document.createElement('HTML_alert');
```

Instead, you should use classes, like this:

```
var _A = document.createElement('div');
_A.className = 'HTML_alert';
```

And in your CSS, instead of `HTML_alert`, you should use `.HTML_alert`.

Comment: Sorry to Say but i am new to `DOM`,And not much having the information of classes in JS so,Please define how to achieve this task by using classes ?

Comment: ok you talk about the `class` but I want this to load before DOM start or while loading,is it not possible to create a `div` before `DOM` loads !because it is a part of `body tag`. So How i'll i get my Solution of Posted Question?

Comment: @AshishMishra Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Ohk i'll try it ,then update you whether its the Solution or not ..@ toothbrush